# pandas join rows/groupby with categorical data and lots of nan values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to simplify a dataframe by joining rows based on 2 columns. Now, the rest is a bit messy with lots of nan values and such. I'll show an example:

initial:

```
    Name    Sex     Shoes       Bike          Car
0   John    Male             Specialised    
1   John    Male             Bridgestone    
2   Lucy    Female                            BMW
3   John    Male    Vans        
4   Lucy    Female  Nike
```

target:

```
    Name    Sex     Shoes   Bike                        Car
0   John    Male    Vans    Specialised, Bridgestone    
1   Lucy    Female  Nike                                BMW
```

What's the function I should use? I couldn't figure out how to do it with *groupby* and the *.agg(','.join)* addition...

(the data above is just exemplary - the one I have to work with has much more many rows with many occurrences of the same name, and about 20 'category' columns... also note, each row should have string in only one of the 'categories' - shoes/bike/car etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add second approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume empty cells are NaN (not empty string), the following will achieve the result,

```
(df.set_index(['Name','Sex']) 
   .groupby(level=[0,1])
   .apply(lambda x:x.apply(lambda y: ', '.join(y.dropna())))
   .reset_index())
```

Second approach,

```
(df.set_index(['Name','Sex'])
   .stack()
   .groupby(level=[0,1,2])
   .apply(', '.join)
   .unstack()
   .reset_index()
```

Comment: this one solves it beautifully, thank you!

Could you please explain how the nested lambda function works? Can't get my head around it.

Comment: No worries :) @veterparga

Comment: the first apply is on each group, the dataframe corresponding to John/Lucy. x here means a dataframe. Within each group, we used a second apply, this is a dataframe apply, which applies a function on each column. here, we join all the nonempty string in a column.

Comment: To sum up, we split dataframe by Name/Sex, and apply (first) operation on each dataframe. Then within each dataframe, we apply (second) a function on each column.

Answer (score 1):

You can `fillna` with an empty string and then clean up the bad data at the end.

---

```
u = df.fillna('').groupby(['Name', 'Sex']).agg(', '.join)
u.stack().str.replace('(, ){2,}|^, |, $', '').unstack()
```

```
            Shoes                      Bike  Car
Name Sex
John Male    Vans  Specialised, Bridgestone
Lucy Female  Nike                            BMW
```

<sub>The order of the regular expression is **very** important</sub>

Answer (score 0):

you can use this using group by like below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['John', 'Male', 'na', 'Specialised', 'na'], ['John', 'Male', 'na', 'Bridgestone', 'na'], ['Lucy', 'Female', 'na', 'na', 'BMW'], ['John', 'Male', 'Vans', 'na', 'na'], ['Lucy', 'Female', 'Nike', 'na', 'na']], columns=('Name', 'Sex', 'Shoes', 'Bike', 'Car'))
df = df.mask(df == "na", '')

df.groupby(["Name", "Sex"]).agg(lambda row: ",".
                                join([val for val in row if val.strip()!=""]))
```